How to use numpy in the process of tensorflow operation
I attempt to use numpy in the framework of tensorflow, but tensorflow cannot see the operations before .eval().
Example Code:
L = 2
tensor = tf.random.uniform((L,L))
with tf.Session() as sess:
      np_data = tensor.eval()
aa = tf.convert_to_tensor(np_data)
# process aa in tensorflow ...
with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True,
      gpu_options=gpu_options)) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(10):
        print(sess.run(([aa, tensor])))

The tensor is varying but aa remains the same! I want to use numpy to undertake some operations and then come back to tensorflow framework, but tensorflow seems can not see the operation before .eval() because aa remains the same!
I expected tensorflow can see the operations before .eval.
Overall, I want to compute like:
# tensorflow operations 
# numpy operations
# tensorflow operations


I'm not entirely sure I grasp your problem, but there is no connection between aa and tensor.  Changing one does not affect the other in any way.  Is that what you're expecting?

I want to integrate numpy into tensorflow framework, but it failed because the operation in tf before .eval can not be seen. That is, in my example, the change in tensor could not affect aa, but what I expect is to affact.

Besides, I try translate numpy into tensorflow instead, but ran into "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78461656/how-to-use-sess-run-in-the-body-of-tf-while-loop" where I need to solve an optimization problem in every step of the loop, it seems wrong to undertake sess.run() in tf.while_loop().

No, aa is a copy -- a snapshot at that point in time.  You might check this article:  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/tf_numpy

Oh thank you! ! ! You are right! I make some mistakes when I test my result. Hence, numpy structure can be directly integrated into tensorflow framework by .eval() and tf.convert_to_tensor(), where the computation can fluently connected, right?

that seems like it would make a good Answer, given it's not totally obvious that aa is a copy (presumably it's a soft copy, which may have some caveats too..)

aa is a tensor evaluated into numpy and converted back to a tensor.  It's going to be a copy.

Actually, if I put .eval() in the process of computation graph, the computation graph could not see the operation before .eval(). (Though aa is a copy, but in computation graph, the copy does not work!) My problem is still unsettled, for I want to undertake numpy operation in my tensorflow computation graph.
