How to use sess.run() in the body of tf.while_loop()
`import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
import numpy as np

L = 2
E = tf.constant([[4.17022005e-01, 7.20324493e-01],[1.14374817e-04, 3.02332573e-01]], dtype=tf.float32)
loss_type = 'l2'
lambda1=0.0
rho = tf.constant(1.0, dtype=tf.float32)
h = tf.constant(np.inf, tf.float32)
w_new =  tf.zeros(([2 * L * L]), dtype=tf.float32)
h_new = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
alpha = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
itera = 0

w_est = tf.Variable(tf.random.uniform([2*L*L], dtype=tf.float32, name="fuck"))


def body(w_new, w_est, itera):
    w_est = tf.get_variable("fuck", shape=(2*L*L))
    optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(
        _func(w_est)[0],_func(w_est)[1], options={'maxiter': 100})
    with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        optimizer.minimize(sess)
        w_new = tf.convert_to_tensor(sess.run(w_est))

        w_est = w_new
        itera += 1
    return w_new, w_est, itera

def cond(w_new, w_est, itera):
    return itera < 10

w_new, w_est, itera = tf.while_loop(cond, body, [w_new, w_est, itera])


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(w_new))`

In the code above, I use optimizer.minimize(sess) in the body of tf.while_loop() and raise error:
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InaccessibleTensorError: Operation 'while/init' has been marked as not fetchable. Typically this happens when it is defined in another function or code block. Use return values,explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it.
I use tensorflow 1.15.4
Expect for solution or replacement of utilizing L-BFGS-B in tensorflow tf.while_loop()

Hi@张德辰, you're trying to use tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface inside a tf.while_loop to perform optimization iteratively. However, there are several issues with your current approach, particularly regarding the compatibility of ScipyOptimizerInterface with TensorFlow 1.x and the way TensorFlow sessions and variables are managed.tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface is part of the deprecated tf.contrib module, which is no longer supported in TensorFlow 2.x and later versions.

In TensorFlow 1.x, you should manage sessions explicitly, but your code mixes old and new session management styles. It's generally better to use the newer tf.compat.v1.Session() consistently or switch to TensorFlow 2.x for a cleaner API.
